# How to use ES6 features to reduce 3 for loops for better performance in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need a solution that can reduce 3 for loops using ES6 features.
In the below, we have two array of objects, in which i have to add a key pair in two places for a matched one.

```
    let rootContent = [
       { 
        'name' : 'varshan',
        'textValues' : [
            { 'id' : 123 , 'value' : 'one' },
            { 'id' : 124 , 'value' : 'two' },
            { 'id' : 125 , 'value' : 'three' },
            { 'id' : 126 , 'value' : 'four' }   
        ]
       },
       {
            'name' : 'kathir',
        'textValues' : [
            { 'id' : 223 , 'value' : 'common' },
            { 'id' : 224 , 'value' : 'maddy' },
            { 'id' : 225 , 'value' : 'winner' },
            { 'id' : 226 , 'value' : 'loser' }  
        ]
       },
       {
            'name' : 'karthika',
        'textValues' : [
            { 'id' : 323 , 'value' : 'sticker' },
            { 'id' : 324 , 'value' : 'kammal' } 
        ]
       },
       {
            'name' : 'lavanya',
        'textValues' : [
            { 'id' : 423 , 'value' : 'beauty' } 
        ]
       } 
    ];

    let incomingContent = [
        {
             'name' : 'lavanya',
         'text_value' : 'beauty'    
        },
        {
             'name' : 'karthika',
         'text_value' : 'kammal'    
        },
        {
             'name' : 'kathir',
         'text_value' : 'maddy' 
        }
    ];
```

The initial step is we have to check whether the name field in the          `incomingContent` array is match with the name field of `rootContent` array, if condition finds true then we have to add a key-value pair with matched as true.

After that we have to find the child of `textValues` array insdie matched object of `rootContent` array with the text_value field of `incomingContent` array, if matched add a key-value pair with matched as true or else false. I attach the expected result below and I need a solution with ES6 features like `map()`, `find()` ....

```
for (let i = 0; i < incomingContent.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < rootContent.length; j++) {
        if (rootContent[j].name === incomingContent[i].name) {
            rootContent[j]['matched'] = true;
            for (let k = 0; k < rootContent[j].textValues.length; k++) {
                rootContent[j].textValues[k]['matched'] =  rootContent[j].textValues[k].value === incomingContent[i].text_value ? true : false;
            }
        }
    }}
```

The output should be like this only.

```
        [
           { 
            'name' : 'varshan',
            'textValues' : [
                { 'id' : 123 , 'value' : 'one' },
                { 'id' : 124 , 'value' : 'two' },
                { 'id' : 125 , 'value' : 'three' },
                { 'id' : 126 , 'value' : 'four' }   
            ]
           },
           {
                'name' : 'kathir',
            'matched' : true,
            'textValues' : [
                { 'id' : 223 , 'value' : 'common' , 'matched' : false},
                { 'id' : 224 , 'value' : 'maddy' , 'matched' : true },
                { 'id' : 225 , 'value' : 'winner' , 'matched' : false},
                { 'id' : 226 , 'value' : 'loser' , 'matched' : false}   
            ]
           },
           {
                'name' : 'karthika',
                'matched' : true,
            'textValues' : [
                { 'id' : 323 , 'value' : 'sticker', 'matched' : false },
                { 'id' : 324 , 'value' : 'kammal' , 'matched' : true }  
            ]
           },
           {
                'name' : 'lavanya',
            'matched' : true,
            'textValues' : [
                { 'id' : 423 , 'value' : 'beauty' , 'matched' : true }  
            ]
           } 
        ]
```

Comment: _"I need a solution that can reduce 3 for loops using ES6 features."_ - Why? If it works then don't "fix" it.

Comment: The code works as is.  Belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was tried a bit using map() and find() to achieve the expected output, but i struggled a bit. I came here to find any better solution than this. @Andreas

Comment: You will want to use a `Map` to lookup the objects by their names, instead of the searching for them every time. But apart from that, nothing is wrong with the loops.

Comment: Sounds Good. @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

Turn one of the arrays into an object indexed by name, and then you'll be able to look up an associated name in `O(1)` time, rather than `O(N)` time. Use `forEach` instead of `for` to avoid having to mess with manual iteration and indicies, and instead of `x === y ? true : false`, just use `x === y`, since that resolves to a Boolean already:

```js
let rootContent=[{'name':'varshan','textValues':[{'id':123,'value':'one'},{'id':124,'value':'two'},{'id':125,'value':'three'},{'id':126,'value':'four'}]},{'name':'kathir','textValues':[{'id':223,'value':'common'},{'id':224,'value':'maddy'},{'id':225,'value':'winner'},{'id':226,'value':'loser'}]},{'name':'karthika','textValues':[{'id':323,'value':'sticker'},{'id':324,'value':'kammal'}]},{'name':'lavanya','textValues':[{'id':423,'value':'beauty'}]}];let incomingContent=[{'name':'lavanya','text_value':'beauty'},{'name':'karthika','text_value':'kammal'},{'name':'kathir','text_value':'maddy'}]

const rootContentByName = rootContent.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.name] = item;
  return a;
}, {});
incomingContent.forEach(({ name, text_value }) => {
  const thisRoot = rootContentByName[name];
  thisRoot.matched = true;
  thisRoot.textValues.forEach((item) => {
    item.matched = item.value === text_value;
  });
});
console.log(rootContent);
```

While array methods are a *bit* slower than `for` loops, they're generally a *lot* more readable, and are probably preferable unless you've run a performance test and have verified that a particular method is taking up too much CPU time.

Comment: Speaking of performance. :) "Use forEach instead of for to avoid having " this might be a bad advice when it comes to perf.

Comment: Reducing the computational complexity has much more of a positive effect. Even then, unless you have something like tens of thousands of items to loop through, it's not something to worry about - 99% of the time, code readability and ease of understanding is more important than micro-optimizations @BabuRajThirumalai

Comment: @BabuRajThirumalai When an answer solves your problem, you can consider accepting / upvoting to indicate that the issue is resolved :)